# Facebook SDK on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook

I have a button in my iOS app to share the currently viewed content on facebook. I'm deciding on the permissions needed for the app, it only needs to write links to the stream, and I don't want to access any of the user information, including the Basic Information, that seems enabled by default. How do I disable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, connecting through Facebook Connect implies the user allows you're app to access minimal informations

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions

Comment: So there is another way of connecting?

Comment: You can, but the user will be always prompting for allowing you to access it's basic informations, at least. Another way which I strongly not recommand, will be to let the user input his facebook password and login email